# JPA ManyToMany deleting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have two classes:

```
public class Keyword {
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "keywords")
  private Set<Thesis> theses = new HashSet<Thesis>();
}


public class Thesis {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Keyword> keywords = new HashSet<Keyword>();
}
```

Now I want to be able to delete a keyword and delete a thesis without associeted objects. How shopuld I do that? I tried with  @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION), did not work, I tried with

```
@PreRemove
void onPreRemove() {

    this.getTheses().clear();
    this.persist();
    this.flush();
}
```

and didn't sucess. What's the correct way to do it?

Ok, seams my solution to set the Set<> to null was not enought. This way it seams to work:

```
@PreRemove
void onPreRemove() {

    log.debug("in preRemove");

    //this.getTheses().clear();
    for (Thesis s : this.getTheses()) {
        s.getKeywords().remove(this);
        s.persist();
        s.flush();
    }
    this.persist();
    this.flush();
    entityManager.flush();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use cascade = ALL if what you want is NO cascade? Don't you think you should remove the keyword from all its theses before deleting it?

Comment: CascadeType.NO does not exist :)

Comment: Don't set any cascade, and you won't have any cascade. The default is no cascading.

Comment: no cascading results in: Server Error: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement;

Comment: *Don't you think you should remove the keyword from all its theses before deleting it*? Otherwise, obviously, theses still reference the deleted keyword, which causes... a ConstraintViolationException

Comment: seams theres no other way, I added a possible solution. I understand why there is a non automatic solution for OneToMany, but in my point of view the framework should provide an automatic remove of ManyToMany. If somebody has an simplier solution I would be glad to hear it....

Comment: Why do you think ManyToMany should automatically clean up your mess?  I think that it's designed appropriately for what it needs to do.  If you need to remove one or the other, you need to remove the references to it, persist, then remove the object.  This can all be done in a transaction, and probably should.